# Pressing backspace whilst typing an SMS causes the screen to exit to the "Delete by Selection" view, how can I stop this?

Tags: sms

As in the title -

When I'm writing a text and hit backspace, it always exits to the 'delete by selection' view for the person I'm writing to. Which is especially annoying b/c when I hit back to escape *that* screen, it takes me to the top of the list of conversations between me and that person, necessitating me spending either a long period of time scrolling, or exiting the menu entirely and beginning again.

Any tips on how I can get it to stop doing this? I have a HTC Desire HD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a thread of people with the same issue.

HTC was contacted an to fix they said factory reset your phone:

> With the phone turned off, press and hold the Volume Down key.
>
> Briefly press the Power key.
>
> Wait for the screen with the 3 Android images to appear.
>
> Press the Volume Down key twice to select CLEAR STORAGE.
>
> Press the Power.
>
> When asked to confirm, press Volume Up

**HOWEVER** this **has not** worked for many users.

The second *fix* would be this:

*hey i will GWY<----- when you make a mistake like that instead of tapping the backspace button to get rid of your mistakes. Press AND HOLD it until it gets rid of your mistakes its a SLIGHT fix but its ALOT easier to have to deal with the whole delete by selection issue